# Disabling error logging in CodeIgniter for a specific helper/library

Tags: codeigniter, logging, mpdf

I am using the mPDF class to generate PDFs from HTML.

While the PDFs show exactly like they should, my CodeIgniter error log gets packed with error notices that seem to be due to some bug in mPDF.

Since these notices are harmless and the PDFs come out perfectly, all I'd like is to disable the CodeIgniter error logging specifically when I run this class.

But I haven't found a way to do this.

Here's my code:

CONTROLLER

```
$this->load->helper('mpdf');
mpdf($html, $filename);
```

HELPER (mpdf_helper.php)

```
function mpdf($html, $filename) 
{
    $CI =& get_instance();
    $CI->config->set_item('log_threshold', 0);
    include('mpdf/mpdf.php');

    $mpdf=new mPDF('', 'letter');
    $mpdf->SetHTMLHeader('powered by example.com');
    $mpdf->WriteHTML($html, 0);
    $mpdf->Output($filename, 'I');
}
```

As you can see I am trying to manually set config for `log_threshold` to `0`, but that does not prevent error logging.

FYI my `index.php` has

```
define('ENVIRONMENT', 'production');
```

which sets `error_reporting(0)`.

Do you know what I should do to stop CodeIgniter from logging errors only when I run mPDF?

ERROR EXAMPLES

```
ERROR - 2012-08-04 23:03:59 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: direction /var/www/vhosts/asd.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 21103

ERROR - 2012-08-04 23:06:07 --> Severity: Notice  --> Undefined index: MARGIN-TOP /var/www/vhosts/asd.com/httpdocs/application/helpers/mpdf/mpdf.php 17271
```

Comment: can you post the error(s) you are getting? You cannot change error_reporting for just one area - it is a system wide function

Comment: these are typically `undefined index` errors that do not affect the PDF output -- I added an example in OP -- any idea how I could selectively suppress errors?

Answer (score 3):

It's because codeigniter's error logging hooked up with [set_error_handler](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php), and php will fire handler whatever the error_reporting value is. As the php manual says:

> ...however you are still able to read the current value of error_reporting and act appropriately.

CI's default error handler doesn't do that for logging (but does for error displaying), [just logs everything that comes in](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/4b838af40d77684539dd40461bd92e6e453fe675/system/core/Exceptions.php#L102) if CI's internal error level demands logging. (the `log_threshold` config value 1, [see the function](https://github.com/bcit-ci/CodeIgniter/blob/4b838af40d77684539dd40461bd92e6e453fe675/system/core/Common.php#L592) called by php error handler.)

If you want to make the CI logger respect the error_logging level you can extend the CI_Exception class with the [standard method](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/core_classes.html) like this:

```
class MY_Exceptions extends CI_Exceptions {
    function log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line) {
        $current_reporting = error_reporting();
        $should_report = $current_reporting & $serverity;

        if ($shoud_report) {
            // call the original implementation if we should report the error
            parent::log_exception($severity, $message, $filepath, $line);
        }
    }
}
```

Once you got this in place, you can fiddle with error_reporting around or in your library calls.

Comment: this looks like a great solution -- how can I use this function (ie, where exactly should I call it in my OP code)?

Comment: The way extending core libraries works is to create a appropriately named file with your class under `application/libraries`, or `application/core` see the "extending core class" part of the [documentation](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/core_classes.html). In your case copy the `MY_Exceptions` class code to `application/core/MY_Exceptions.php` file and CI should pick it up automatically (mind the uppercase/lowercase chars).